# I'm looking for suggestions for an automated deployment tool that will fit into my continuous integration plan

Tags: tomcat, continuous-integration, hudson, deployment

I've started using Hudson based upon a suggestion from a co-worker, and I really enjoy it. However, he is pointing Hudson to Maven to handle deployments of the WAR, while I am using Ant for a legacy project. I know Ant has a deployment task that I could tell Hudson to run, but it works with the Tomcat manager (not an option), and you have to give your username and password in plain text in the build file. I would prefer a solution where I can basically give it the commands I run, and for server login point it at the location of my public/private key. I'm on a Windows XP Pro machine when I'm doing the deploy. I'm really looking for the simplest and most straightforward solution, and if that means storing my username/password in a build file then I can handle that.

Comment: If you're stuck with ant and just want to tell it which commands to run could you just use the exec task?

Answer (score 2):

How about using the ant [scptask](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html) ?

You will be able to use ssh private/public keys and it's very simple, provided you have ssh access to your deployment server.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question right. 
If i were you, I'd explore one or a combination of the following: (This is based on the various options I have tried in my own work)

1. Set up a Master-Slave configuration, get the deploy project running on one or more target environment hosts (which are configured to behave as slaves). Get the required commands to run as projects either via batch scripts or ant tasks (like sshexec, exec mentioned above). You can use the "mask the password" plugin (mask-passwords.hpi) in hudson to provide a level of masking in the build log files etc.,
2. Use PSTools to run the required scripts/commands via hudson builds on a remote host (which would be your target environment hosts). This does not require master-slave config etc., but would need PSTools to be in your host from which you are running hudson.

Hope this helps.